# Should the education section on the career site be more flexible/general?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, cv

It specifically asks about technology which seems to imply programming languages or database technology. What if you studied biology or chemistry? In my case I have business school info (gasp! horror!) that I would like to add but not sure how well it fits. Any suggestions or examples of how others have done this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the *Background* field as a workaround and mention there that you studied Biology or Chemistry.